# How to activate editing cell mode automatically when moving to a cell - Datagrid MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, mui-x-data-grid

My problem is that the editing mode is not activated to start editing the value when I move with the arrows up or down each cell in the "Age" column.

I have this little example, I want the edit mode to activate automatically when I am moving (up or down arrowdown/arrowup) through each cell of the "Age" column. That is, when I move from cell 1 with arrowdown to cell 2, cell 2 must be ready to write the value. i tried a few things but nothing works, i leave a simple and clean codesandbox to fork if anyone can help me there, thanks since now

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/optimistic-keldysh-x6msdn?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A26%2C7

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example